# NANs, Infinities, and very large losses with normalizing flows

Tags: loss-function, transformer, normalization, generative-models

I am new to normalizing flows and have been trying to use them with a high-dimensional dataset, and I have been running into very large numbers and errors with sampling that don't occur when I use a lower dimensional toy dataset. What are some possible causes/solutions to this? Could it be an issue with how the data is normalized? (My data is currently normalized to values between 0 and 1), or are there specific types of transforms/permutations/other layers that are commonly used to prevent this? I know normalizing flows have been relatively successful at a previous similar task to this one (with the same dimensionality), so I am assuming there is something wrong with my setup/hyperparameters.